# How to change the color of the background of an image?

Tags: image-processing, color, image

I have an image, and I want to change the color of its background. For example, I want to change the color of the sky from blue to green (or just to pure-white, for simplicity). I have already get the edge of the house, i.e. `imgEdges2` (my method of getting the `imgEdges2` is very ad-hoc, and any advice for improvement is also welcome), how can I change the color of the sky?

Many thanks!

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
imgEdges = EdgeDetect[img, 6.7, 0.11];
edgeData = ImageData@imgEdges;
edgeData[[246 ;; 256, All]] = 0;
edgeData[[80 ;; 120, 100 ;; 256]] = 0;
edgeData[[60 ;; 79, 90 ;; 154]] = 0;
edgeData[[50 ;; 59, 90 ;; 110]] = 0;
edgeData[[57 ;; 59, 111 ;; 115]] = 0;
imgEdges2 =Image@edgeData
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a first suggestion, you might try something like:

`Manipulate[ColorReplace[#,First@DominantColors@#->rep,d]&@img,{d,0,.1}]`

This will more or less work if your background is a solid color and is dominant in the image. You can replace the `First` with a manual index after `DominantColors` if it's not dominant. The `Manipulate` lets you figure out the right thresholding. This doesn't do anything with edge detection or morphological binarization, though—there's certainly more to be done! 

This gets me [this](https://i.imgur.com/qogbmON.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];

edge = ImageMultiply[EdgeDetect[ImageSubtract[#3, #] & @@ ColorSeparate[img], 4, 0.04],
    Image[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Min[i, j] <= 100 -> 1}, ImageDimensions[img]]]]

binary = Binarize[ImageMultiply[ImageSubtract[#3, #] & @@ ColorSeparate[img],
    Image[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Min[i, j] <= 100 -> 1}, ImageDimensions[img]]]], 0.12]

sky = Nest[ImageAdd[ImageFilter[Min, ImageFilter[Max, #, 1], 1], edge] &,
           ImageFilter[Min, ImageAdd[binary, edge], 1], 2]

ImageAdd[
   ImageMultiply[ImageApply[{#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[1]]} &, img], #],
   ImageMultiply[img, ColorNegate[#]]] & /@ {sky, sky - edge}
```

[image] $\hspace{1.5cm}$ [image]

Answer (score 8):

There are built in functions for this. Remove background

```
RemoveBackground[img]
```

[image]

Replace the background with a different color:

```
RemoveAlphaChannel[RemoveBackground[img], Green]
```

[image]

That works because removal of background is done with help of setting the alpha channel with mask:

```
AlphaChannel[RemoveBackground[img]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

Get the Image:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
```

Use RegionBinarize to get a mask, and then close up the holes:

```
backgroundMask = ColorNegate[FillingTransform[Closing[RegionBinarize[img, ColorNegate @ Binarize @ img, 0.25], 5]]];
```

Choose the color to be targetted based on what occurs in the mask:

```
backgroundColor = RGBColor[Median[DeleteCases[Flatten[ImageData[backgroundMask img], 1], {0., 0., 0.}]]];
```

Make the replacement through the whole image:

```
colorReplacedImg = ColorReplace[img, backgroundColor -> Red];
```

Arithmetic so the replacement is only kept inside the mask:

```
resultImg = colorReplacedImg backgroundMask + ColorNegate[backgroundMask] img
```

[image: Very dramatic and maybe unsettling sunset created with ColorReplace]